# Maven build war not update code

Tags: maven, spring-mvc

I am working on Spring hibernate project.When i clean install war and the change is not change in war.I delete all controllers in my project and
clean install >> refresh >> delete old war >> deploy.After deploy page open means Controller call.This problem is so complicated.can anyone help me Please.

Comment: Without the pom file the code or a link to the project and detailed informations which maven versions etc. you are using...Using maven on plain command line?

Comment: @khmarbaise my project is multimodule and version is 3.3.9